# Python Tkinter Canvas get line cardinal direction

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, line, tkinter-canvas

I have two points on a tkinter canvas. I need a function to determine which cardinal direction a line drawn between them would be the closest to (N, NW, W SW, S etc.) (Direction matters)? How would I go about doing this? Please note that in a canvas, the top-left is (0,0).

I have tried:

```
def dot_product(self, v, w):
    return v[0]*w[0]+v[1]*w[1]
def inner_angle(self, v, w):
    cosx=self.dot_product(v,w)/(sqrt(v[0]**2+v[1]**2)*sqrt(w[0]**2+w[1]**2))
    rad=acos(cosx)
    return rad*180/pi
def getAngle(self, A, B):
    inner=self.inner_angle(A,B)
    det = A[0]*B[1]-A[1]*B[0]
    if det<0:
        return inner
    else:
        return 360-inner
```

and:

```
def getBearing(self, pointA, pointB):

if (type(pointA) != tuple) or (type(pointB) != tuple):
    raise TypeError("Only tuples are supported as arguments")

lat1 = math.radians(pointA[0])
lat2 = math.radians(pointB[0])

diffLong = math.radians(pointB[1] - pointA[1])

x = math.sin(diffLong) * math.cos(lat2)
y = math.cos(lat1) * math.sin(lat2) - (math.sin(lat1) * math.cos(lat2) * math.cos(diffLong))

initial_bearing = math.atan2(x, y)

initial_bearing = math.degrees(initial_bearing)
compass_bearing = (initial_bearing + 360) % 360

return compass_bearing
```

(I used this function to get direction (The code is incomplete, it's more of an example))

```
def findDirection(self, p1, p2):
    bearing = self.getBearing(p1, p2) # OR getAngle()
    print(bearing)
    index = [180, 0]
    closest = min(index, key=lambda x:abs(x-bearing))
    if closest == 10:
        print(str(bearing) + " : UP")
    elif closest == 360:
        print(str(bearing) + " : DOWN")
    elif closest == 0:
        print(str(bearing) + " : RIGHT")
    elif closest == 180:
        print(str(bearing) + " : LEFT")
```

None of those work. The result doesn't seem to be consistent enough to use.
Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my proposed approach to determine the closest compass direction to the one pointed at by a line segment `[A, B]` defined by its end points `point_a` and `point_b`:

1. All calculations are done in standard cartesian coordinates, the
   change to screen coordinates is done at the end. that simplifies the
   approach, and makes the code re-usable elsewhere.
2. First change the origin to `point_a`
3. second calculate the angle of the line segment with the x_axis
4. determine the closest bearing (in standard cartesian coordinates)
5. convert the standard bearing to screen coordinates bearings (a horizontal flip)

> **with points defined in screen coordinates (Y axis down), call `get_bearings(point_a, point_b)`**
>   If the points defined in standard
>   cartesian coordinates (Y axis up), call
>   `assign_bearing_to_compass(point_a, point_b)`
>   (The tests underneath the code show the results of using points in standard coordinates, and screen coordinates.)

---

```
import math


def _change_origin_of_point_b_to_point_a(point_a, point_b):
    # uses standard Y axis orientation, not screen orientation
    return (point_b[0] - point_a[0], point_b[1] - point_a[1])

def _calc_angle_segment_a_b_with_x_axis(point_a, point_b):
    # uses standard Y axis orientation, not screen orientation
    xa, ya = point_a
    xb, yb = _change_origin_of_point_b_to_point_a(point_a, point_b)
    return math.atan2(yb, xb)

def determine_bearing_in_degrees(point_a, point_b):
    """returns the angle in degrees that line segment [point_a, point_b)]
       makes with the horizontal X axis 
    """
    # uses standard Y axis orientation, not screen orientation
    return _calc_angle_segment_a_b_with_x_axis(point_a, point_b) * 180 / math.pi

def assign_bearing_to_compass(point_a, point_b):
    """returns the standard bearing of line segment [point_a, point_b)
    """
    # uses standard Y axis orientation, not screen orientation    
    compass = {'W' : [157.5, -157.5], 
               'SW': [-157.5, -112.5], 
               'S' : [-112.5, -67.5], 
               'SE': [-67.5, -22.5], 
               'E' : [-22.5, 22.5], 
               "NE": [22.5, 67.5], 
               'N' : [67.5, 112.5], 
               'NW': [112.5, 157.5]}

    bear = determine_bearing_in_degrees(point_a, point_b)
    for direction, interval in compass.items():
        low, high = interval
        if bear >= low and bear < high:
            return direction
    return 'W'

def _convert_to_negative_Y_axis(compass_direction):
    """flips the compass_direction horizontally
    """
    compass_conversion = {'E' : 'E', 
                          'SE': 'NE', 
                          'S' : 'N', 
                          'SW': 'NW', 
                          'W' : 'W', 
                          "NW": 'SW', 
                          'N' : 'S', 
                          'NE': 'SE'}
    return compass_conversion[compass_direction]

def get_bearings(point_a, point_b):
    return _convert_to_negative_Y_axis(assign_bearing_to_compass(point_a, point_b))
```

## Tests:

(using the standard trigonometric circle quadrants)

### Quadrant I:

```
point_a = (0, 0)
points_b = [(1, 0), (1, 3), (1, 2), (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (0, 1)]
print("point_a, point_b     Y_up     Y_down (in screen coordinates)")
for point_b in points_b:
    print(point_a, ' ', point_b, '      ', assign_bearing_to_compass(point_a, point_b), '        ', get_bearings(point_a, point_b))
```

#### results:

```
point_a, point_b     Y_up     Y_down (in screen coordinates)
(0, 0)   (1, 0)        E          E
(0, 0)   (1, 3)        N          S
(0, 0)   (1, 2)        NE         SE
(0, 0)   (1, 1)        NE         SE
(0, 0)   (2, 1)        NE         SE
(0, 0)   (3, 1)        E          E
(0, 0)   (0, 1)        N          S
```

### Quadrant II:

```
point_a = (0, 0)
points_b = [(-1, 0), (-1, 3), (-1, 2), (-1, 1), (-2, 1), (-3, 1), (0, 1)]
print("point_a, point_b     Y_up     Y_down (in screen coordinates)")
for point_b in points_b:
    print(point_a, ' ', point_b, '      ', assign_bearing_to_compass(point_a, point_b), '        ', get_bearings(point_a, point_b))
```

#### results:

```
point_a, point_b     Y_up     Y_down (in screen coordinates)
(0, 0)   (-1, 0)       W          W
(0, 0)   (-1, 3)       N          S
(0, 0)   (-1, 2)       NW         SW
(0, 0)   (-1, 1)       NW         SW
(0, 0)   (-2, 1)       NW         SW
(0, 0)   (-3, 1)       W          W
(0, 0)   (0, 1)        N          S
```

### Quadrant III:

```
point_a = (0, 0)
points_b = [(-1, 0), (-1, -3), (-1, -2), (-1, -1), (-2, -1), (-3, -1), (0, -1)]
print("point_a, point_b     Y_up     Y_down (in screen coordinates)")
for point_b in points_b:
    print(point_a, ' ', point_b, '      ', assign_bearing_to_compass(point_a, point_b), '        ', get_bearings(point_a, point_b))
```

#### results:

```
point_a, point_b     Y_up     Y_down (in screen coordinates)
(0, 0)   (-1, 0)        W          W
(0, 0)   (-1, -3)       S          N
(0, 0)   (-1, -2)       SW         NW
(0, 0)   (-1, -1)       SW         NW
(0, 0)   (-2, -1)       SW         NW
(0, 0)   (-3, -1)       W          W
(0, 0)   (0, -1)        S          N
```

### Quadrant IV:

```
point_a = (0, 0)
points_b = [(1, 0), (1, -3), (1, -2), (1, -1), (2, -1), (3, -1), (0, -1)]
print("point_a, point_b     Y_up     Y_down (in screen coordinates)")
for point_b in points_b:
    print(point_a, ' ', point_b, '      ', assign_bearing_to_compass(point_a, point_b), '        ', get_bearings(point_a, point_b))
```

#### results:

```
point_a, point_b     Y_up     Y_down (in screen coordinates)
(0, 0)   (1, 0)        E          E
(0, 0)   (1, -3)       S          N
(0, 0)   (1, -2)       SE         NE
(0, 0)   (1, -1)       SE         NE
(0, 0)   (2, -1)       SE         NE
(0, 0)   (3, -1)       E          E
(0, 0)   (0, -1)       S          N
```

Comment: Your solution works perfectly! Except for the fact that you have "W" and "E" mixed up. That doesn't matter though. Thank you!

Comment: Wonderful, I am glad I could help. I corrected the `W<->E` mishap, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is of help -- I implemented it for (my) convenience using Python turtle which is built on tkinter.  I switched turtle into ***logo*** mode which makes North 0 degrees and positive angles clockwise (i.e. East is 90 degrees) like a compass.  The turtle method `towards()` does most of what you want so I tried to emulate it when calculating the cardinal directions:

```
from random import randrange
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
from math import pi, atan2, degrees

DIRECTIONS = ['N', 'NNE', 'NE', 'ENE', 'E', 'ESE', 'SE', 'SSE', 'S', 'SSW', 'SW', 'WSW', 'W', 'WNW', 'NW', 'NNW']

BUCKET = 360.0 / len(DIRECTIONS)

X, Y = 0, 1

SIZE = 500

def onclick_handler(x, y):
    # Draw random vector

    yertle.reset()
    yertle.hideturtle()
    yertle.penup()

    start = (randrange(-SIZE//2, SIZE//2), randrange(-SIZE//2, SIZE//2))
    end = (randrange(-SIZE//2, SIZE//2), randrange(-SIZE//2, SIZE//2))

    yertle.goto(start)
    yertle.dot()
    yertle.showturtle()
    yertle.pendown()
    yertle.setheading(yertle.towards(end))
    yertle.goto(end)

    # Compute vector direction

    x, y = end[X] - start[X], end[Y] - start[Y]

    angle = round(degrees(atan2(y, -x) - pi / 2), 10) % 360.0

    direction = DIRECTIONS[round(angle / BUCKET) % len(DIRECTIONS)]

    screen.title("{} degress is {}".format(round(angle, 2), direction))

yertle = Turtle()

screen = Screen()
screen.mode('logo')
screen.setup(SIZE, SIZE)
screen.onclick(onclick_handler)

onclick_handler(0, 0)

screen.mainloop()
```

The program draws a random line (with obvious start point and direction) and calculations the cardinal direction which can be found in the window title.  Clicking on the window generates a new line and calculation.

You should be able to work with 8 or 32 compass points by editing the `DIRECTIONS` variable.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To obtain a cardinal direction, a dictionary with angles (in this case degrees) referencing the relevant direction is needed:

```
directions = {0:"N", 45:"NE", 90:"E", 135:"SE", 180:"S",
              225:"SW", 270:"W", 315:"NW", 360:"N"}
```

Note that north is added twice, as an angle obtained of 350 degrees between 2 points would give north-west, when it should give north.

Let two points on the Tkinter canvas, `a` and `b`have coordinates `(x1, y1)` and `(x2, y2)` respectively. Thus, the difference between them (`dx` and `dy`) is `x1-x2` and `y1-y2`.

You can now perform the inverse tangent of `dy/dx` to obtain an angle. It is worth pointing out that if `dx` is 0, then it would divide by 0. You can prevent this by adding `if not dx: return "N"`, returning North if the points have the same x value.

Furthermore, if dx is greater than 0 then it will return the same as if it was less than 0. This is as the tangent graph has a period of 180 degrees. To counteract this, you can just add `if dx > 0: angle += 180`.

Now that you have an angle, you can reference it within the `directions` dictionary defined earlier, using Pythons inbuilt `min` function: `min(self.directions, key=lambda x: abs(x-angle))`. This returns the closest degree specified in the dictionary. To obtain the cardinal value, we can then access this within the dictionary.

Putting this all together gives the following function **(TLDR)**:

```
from math import atan, degrees

...

def get_cardinal(a, b):
    dx, dy = a[0]-b[0], a[1]-b[1]
    if not dx:
        return "N"
    angle = degrees(atan(dy/dx))+90 #+90 to take into account TKinters coordinate system.
    if dx > 0:
        angle += 180
    return directions[min(directions, key=lambda x: abs(x-angle))]
```

This, combined with the `directions` dictionary gives you your answer.

Comment: This works great, except when you have a line with only change in the y axis. It will return "N" whether the direction is north or south because of - if not dx: return "N".